# jasperphp error passing parameters

Tags: php, jasper-reports, jasper-plugin

In a jasper report I have a sql sentence like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table $P!{my_where}
```

In my php program, I'm calling the report this way:

```
    JasperPHP::process(
        base_path() . '/app/reports/report.jasper', 
        false,
        array("pdf"),
        array("my_where" => "WHERE field = value"),
        \Config::get('database.connections.mysql')
        )->execute();
```

Then, this is the error message:

> Wrong report param format!

Doing it the simple way works, I mean:

In the report:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE $P!{field} = $P{value}
```

In PHP:

```
    JasperPHP::process(
        base_path() . '/app/reports/report.jasper', 
        false,
        array("pdf"),
        array("field" => $my_field, "value" => $my_value),
        \Config::get('database.connections.mysql')
        )->execute();
```

The thing is, I need to build a where clause dynamically from several fields, so, passing a only "where" parameter is a must.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: is just necessary to double quote the parameter:

```
$my_where = '"' .  $my_where . '"';

JasperPHP::process(
    base_path() . '/app/reports/report.jasper', 
    false,
    array("pdf"),
    array("my_where" => $my_where),
    \Config::get('database.connections.mysql')
    )->execute();
```

Comment: Would you please tell me How you set the database parameters in \Config:get('database.connections.mysql')?

Comment: Sorry for responding so late. I build the sentence in Laravel exactly as shown:

\Config::get('database.connections.mysql')

But it depends on the framework you are using.